# How to fill textbox values in dynamically created rows in an HTML Table using jQuery

Tags: html, html-table

I have started learning jQuery recently and need help in writing a script - I'm doing this as practice.

My code for the HTML is below.

On button click I want to create rows in the table and fill values from textbox using jQuery

```
<html>
  <head>
<scriptsrc="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script></script>
</head>
 <body><br>
      First Name<br><input type ="text" id="firstname"></input><br><br>
      Employee ID<br><input type="text" id="empid"></input><br><br>
      Phone No<br><input type="text"    id="phnno"></input><br><br>
      <button type="button" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button><br><br><br>

 <table id="mytable" border="1" class="tbinput" style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>EmployeeID</th>     
    <th>Phone No</th>
  </tr>
</table> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery .append("any dom element").

As a example i added a snippet in your code

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document)
  .ready(
    function() {
      $(document).on("click","#btnSubmit",function(){
                                      $("#mytable").append("<tr><td>"+$("#firstname").val()+"</td><td>"+$("#empid").val()+"</td><td>"+$("#phnno").val()+"</td></tr>");
                                                   }
               )
});
</script>
</head>
 <body><br>
      First Name<br><input type ="text" id="firstname"></input><br><br>
      Employee ID<br><input type="text" id="empid"></input><br><br>
      Phone No<br><input type="text"    id="phnno"></input><br><br>
      <button type="button" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button><br><br><br>

 <table id="mytable" border="1" class="tbinput" style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>EmployeeID</th>     
    <th>Phone No</th>
  </tr>
</table> 

</body>
</html>
```

```html
 $("#mytable").append("<tr><td>"+$("#firstname").val()+"</td><td>"+$("#empid").val()+"</td><td>"+$("#phnno").val()+"</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Thanks Girish , i wrote exactly the same with your first Hint and it worked .         Thanks again for the whole snippet :p

Answer (score -1):

http://devzone.co.in/add-remove-rows-in-table-dynamically-using-jquery/

This Link helps you to adding a HTML table row along with textbox values